# Hiding a div automatically when other related divs are also hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page consists of several *elements*, *buttons* and *scrollers*. Each button is to hide/unhide a group of elements, and each scroller is to scroll to the first element of the group. I use `onclick` events to hide, unhide and scroll, and they all work fine. What I'm trying and failing to do is hiding the *scroller* automatically when all related elements are hidden.

EXAMPLE: When I click `scroller`, page goes to `Element 1a`. When I click 1st `button` it hides/unhides Element 1a, 1b and 1c, and click 2nd `button` it does the same for Element 1d, 1e, 1f. I need my `scroller` to be hidden automatically when there's no visible `element` left in the page which are connected with this scroller. How can I fix my js code to achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div class="element">Element 1a</div>
<div class="element">Element 1b</div>
<div class="element">Element 1c</div>
<div class="element">Element 1d</div>
<div class="element">Element 1e</div>
<div class="element">Element 1f</div>
...

<div class="button" onclick="hide1()">Hide/Unhide 1a,1b,1c</div>
<div class="button" onclick="hide2()">Hide/Unhide 1d,1e,1f</div>
<div class="scroller" onclick="scroll1()">Scroll to Element 1</div>

<script>window.onload = hidescroller()</script>
```

JS:

```
function hidescroller() {
   var scroller = document.getElementsByClassName("scroller")[0];
   var element = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
   var i;
   for (i=0; i<element.length; i++) {
      if (element[i].style.display = "none") {
         scroller.style.display = "none";
      }
      else {
         scroller.style.display = "block";
      }
   }
}
```

I'm happy with my `hide1()`, `hide2()` and `scroll1()` functions, so in order to avoid confusion I didn't write them. If you need to see them too, just let me know.

Comment: you have to hide scroller in the hide1 function. Select the button element and then use button.nextElementSibling then hide it. If you share your hide1 function I can give more support.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but it's not exactly what I need. In order to clarify the question, I divide `hide1` function into `hide1` and `hide2` now

Comment: This looks like it might benefit from `useState` and `useEffect` React Hooks. You can have an `onClick` event which updates state and a `useEffect` hook which listens for changes to the state.